# Editing several Inputs in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I've started to learn React and tried to make an household book, which is based on the code of an Todo App of the MDN-React-Tutorial (https://github.com/mdn/todo-react/blob/master/src/components/Todo.js)

I got stuck at editing the inputs from the entries. In difference to a todo-app I want to edit several inputs at the same time and update these entries with the entered inputs.

I'm pretty sure that there is a mistake at the editTask()-Function, but I can't spot the mistake! I really appreciate your help!

This is what my code looks like!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Entry(props) {

const[newState, setNewState] = useState({
  entry: "",
  status: "",
  betrag: "",
  kategorie: "",
  datum: ""
});

function handleChange(e) {      
  const value = e.target.value;

  setNewState({
    ...newState,
    [e.target.name]: value
  });
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  props.editTask(props.id, newState);
  setNewState("");
  setEditing(false); 
  console.log("newState: " + newState);
  console.log("setNewState: " + setNewState);
  console.log("props.id: " + props.id);
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input 
      id={props.id}
      type="text"
      name="entry"
      value={newState.entry}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <input 
      id={props.id}
      type="text"
      name="status"
      value={newState.status}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <input 
      id={props.id}
      type="text"
      name="betrag"
      value={newState.betrag}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <input 
      id={props.id}
      type="text"
      name="kategorie"
      value={newState.kategorie}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <input 
      id={props.id}
      type="text"
      name="datum"
      value={newState.datum}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />

    <br></br>
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => setEditing(false)}
    >
      Cancel
    </button>
    <button
      type="submit"
    >
      Save
    </button>
  </form>
);
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import Entry from "./components/Entry";
import Form from "./components/Form2";

function App(props) {

  function editTask(id, newState) {
    const editedTaskList = tasks.map(task => {
      if (id === task.id) {
        //
        const editTask = { id: "todo-" + nanoid(), name: newState.entry, ausgabe_einnahme: newState.status, betrag: newState.betrag, kategorie: newState.kategorie, datum: newState.datum};
        return {...task, editTask}
      }
      return task;
    });
  
    setTasks(editedTaskList);
  }

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(props.tasks);
  const taskList = tasks.map(task => (
        <Entry 
          id={task.id}
          name={task.name}
          completed={task.completed}
          key={task.id}
          toggleTaskCompleted={toggleTaskCompleted}
          deleteTask={deleteTask}
          editTask={editTask}

          ausgabe_einnahme={task.ausgabe_einnahme}
          betrag={task.betrag}
          kategorie={task.kategorie}
          datum={task.datum}
        />
      )
  );
  
  return (
    <div className="bilanzo">
      <h1>Bilanzo</h1>
      <div className="overview">
      <p>
        <span><strong>Einnahmen & Ausgaben!</strong></span>
      </p>
      <h2 id="list-heading">{headingText}</h2>
        <ul className="entry">
          {taskList}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <Form addTask={addTask} />
    </div>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is `setEditing` in the first snippet? It isn't defined anywhere. Can you explain more what you are stuck on? Is there an error, unexpected behavior, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure:

```
return {...task, editTask}
```

is right, perhaps it should be:

```
return {...task, ...editTask}
```

Comment: Yeah! It worked! Thank you a lot!
But what exactly do these three dots mean?

Comment: I that's called spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax ; basically, I think of it as a way to give you all the entries of a thing; in this case we're sort of saying 'add all of the entries of editTask to this object that I'm creating'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at the **return** of editMethod() and it can be written as follows:

```
  function editTask(id, newState) {
    const editedTaskList = tasks.map(task => {
      if (id === task.id) {
       
        const editTask = { id: "todo-" + nanoid(), name: newState.entry, ausgabe_einnahme: newState.status, betrag: newState.betrag, kategorie: newState.kategorie, datum: newState.datum};

        return {...task, nameTask: newState} // FIX
      }
      return task;
    });
  
    setTasks(editedTaskList);
  }
```

> The JavaScript **Spread operator** (...) allows us to quickly copy all or part of an existing array or object into another array or object.